# Objective-c Memory warning

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make some kind of puzzles, but after 5-10 shuffles I receive memory warning, and now I am trying just to add puzzle and remove it from super view but, however, there is still some kind of memory leek.. could some one help me please?

```
- (void)setup6x6
{
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

            cor = arc4random()%4;
            nCor = arc4random()%8;
            maxCor = arc4random()%16;

            scale = _pImage.size.width / puzzleArea.frame.size.width;
            NSString * imageName1;
            UIImage * imageToMask1;
            UIImage * maskedImage1;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    imageName1 = [topLeftCornerPuzzles objectAtIndex:cor];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                              58 * i * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale)];
                }
                else if (j == 5)
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[topRightCornerPuzzles objectAtIndex:cor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake((42 + 50*(j-1)) * scale,
                                                                              58 * i * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale)];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[topPuzzles objectAtIndex:nCor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake((42 + 50*(j-1)) * scale,
                                                                              58 * i * scale,
                                                                              66 * scale,
                                                                              58* scale)];
                }
            }
            else if (i < 5)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[leftPuzzles objectAtIndex:nCor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                              (42 + 50*(i-1)) * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale,
                                                                              66 * scale)];
                }
                else if (j == 5)
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[rightPuzzles objectAtIndex:nCor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake((42 + 50*(j-1)) * scale,
                                                                              (42 + 50*(i-1)) * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale,
                                                                              66 * scale)];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[middlePuzzles objectAtIndex:maxCor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake((42 + 50*(j-1)) * scale,
                                                                              (42 + 50*(i-1)) * scale,
                                                                              66 * scale,
                                                                              66 * scale)];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[bottomLeftCornerPuzzles objectAtIndex:cor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                              (42 + 50*(i-1)) * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale)];
                }
                else if (j == 5)
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[bottomRightCornerPuzzles objectAtIndex:cor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake((42 + 50*(j-1)) * scale,
                                                                              (42 + 50*(i-1)) * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale)];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageName1 = [self checkPreviousInArray6x6:puzzles new:[bottomPuzzles objectAtIndex:nCor] index:num];
                    imageToMask1 = [self cropImage:_pImage withRect:CGRectMake((42 + 50*(j-1)) * scale,
                                                                              (42 + 50*(i-1)) * scale,
                                                                              66 * scale,
                                                                              58 * scale)];
                }
            }
            [puzzles addObject:imageName1];
            maskedImage1 = [self maskImage:imageToMask1 withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName1]];
            [imgView setImage:maskedImage1];

            if (i == 0)
                originY = 0;
            else
                originY = 50 * (i-1) + 42;

            if (j == 0)
                originX = 0;
            else
                originX = 50 * (j-1) + 42;

            if (j == 0 || j == 5)
                sizeW = 58;
            else
                sizeW = 66;

            if (i == 0 || i == 5)
                sizeH = 58;
            else
                sizeH = 66;

            [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeW, sizeH)];
            [puzzleArea addSubview:imgView];
            [imgView removeFromSuperview];
            //[maskedImage1 release];
            imageToMask1 = nil;
            maskedImage1 = nil;
            [imgView release];
            [imageName1 release];
            //[imageToMask1 release];
            num += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

There is how I crop:

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image withRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropRect)];
}
```

And there is how I mask:

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImg
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImg.CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                        NULL,
                                        false);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask)];
    CGImageRelease(maskRef);
    CGImageRelease(mask);
}
```

I can't understand why do I receive a memory warning if I release everything. However, if i try to release maskedImage1 or imageToMask1 I also receive error...

Comment: You're running an O(n^2) algorithm that repeatedly bangs on a method that makes cropped images.  Why do you think you're getting memory warnings?

Comment: @CodaFi when n=6, O(n^2) is the same as O(1). Not saying this is the most efficient method, but it should be "fast enough". (Evidenced by the fact that it works the first few times according to the question)

Comment: Even if you are allocating an deleting resources correctly, you simply have too many UIImageViews. Just create 1 view and then create CALayers that will be placed inside that view. Set the contents for each CALayer dynamically and you should be fine. What you are doing here is creating all the images in memory, that is very poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create a `CGImage`, you need to release it.  The `UIImage` will not do that for you.

You should not release a `CGImage` if you didn't create it. In your second method, you should *not* do `CGImageRelease(maskRef)`.

When you `return` from a method, the code after that statement is not executed.

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image withRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    CGImageRef croppedCGImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropRect);
    UIImage *croppedUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(croppedCGImage);
    return croppedUIImage;
}

- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImg
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImg.CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                        NULL,
                                        false);
    CGImageRef maskedCGImage = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *maskedUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(maskedCGImage);
    CGImageRelease(mask);
    return maskedUIImage;
}
```

Comment: Memory warnings aren't just caused by leaks.  He's expecting iOS devices to have the horsepower of some higher-end computers.

Comment: Sure, but don't you think the leaks are important to fix first?

Comment: No!  I think he needs to consider a better algorithm first.  Generating a grid of images, however large, needs to be done with performance in mind, not just brute forced in a couple of loops.  The memory leaks are trivial, and the static analyzer can always yell at him about them, but one cannot polish a turd and complain about the smell.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, it didn't help me. Still after 7-8 shuffles I receive a memory warning.

Comment: In fact, I have an application where I have an image which I should crop to puzzles (3x3, 5x5, 6x6, 8x8). I decided to do it with loop, 6x6 and I make a imageview, then I have imageName (0_1_1_1.png) for example for puzzles (each number shows what every side has like in puzzles) and with "checkPreviousInArray" i check if puzzles are correct, if not i return other imageName and then i crop image to rectangles which will be masked with Mask which i will get with "imageName".

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is "release everything you own"

You gain ownership of an object whenever you call a method starting with `alloc`, `copy`, `new`, or `retain` (these are just conventions, but a lot of Objective-C is).

You lose ownership of an object whenever you call `release` or `autorelease`.

If we look at your code with these guidelines, you can see that you're releasing several objects that you never own.

- You correctly `alloc` and then `release` `imgView`
- You release `imageName1` without ever allocating, copying, or retaining it. This can cause crashes. (I'm assuming `checkPreviousInArray6x6:new:index:` doesn't return an object it owns).

for `MaskImage:withMask:` the CG types follow similar rules.

- `maskRef` is never retained, copied, etc. so it shouldn't be released.
- `mask` is being properly created and released.

However, there's a big problem with this method: the lines after `return` never get called, so the memory never gets cleaned up.

I would recommend running the static analyzer on your code, as there are many errors that it could help catch.

For the full gory details of manual memory management, I recommend reading the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)